# Select Distinct CSV Column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Lets say I have a column with CSV values: `a,b,c,d`

I have a table-function `dbo.Split(@Data varchar,@Delimeter varchar)` that returns them in rows, but not sure how it would apply here.

So lets say I'm trying to gather all the distinct values from one column to multiple rows.

If I do a `Distinct`, I'm going to get the eventual:

```
 Column
-------------------------------------
 b
 a,b,c
 c,d
 d
```

What I would like to return is this:

```
 Column
-------------------------------------
 a
 b
 c
 d
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
  (
     name VARCHAR(10)
  )

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES     ('b'),
            ('a,b,c'),
            ('c,d'),
            ('d')

SELECT DISTINCT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') data
FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(name, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
        FROM   #temp) AS A
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

Comment: Thanks, but don't you have a solution that's a bit less server resource intensive?